# how to introduce a database on server in c# database programming with linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a small c# program which is connected to the the database with linq to sql .
now I want to put the database on server so 2 or 3 different people could connect to it , how and where should I give the new address of the database in my codes ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to update the connection string in the configuration file. Depending on the project type this could differ, either being in a web.config or an app.config, within the `<connectionStrings />` element.

If it's a library/dll project then although it will likely have an `app.config` storing the connection string for the designer, the instance will pick it up from the configuration of the calling application.